# spring boot thymeleaf - pass dropdown selected value as PathVariable

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to pass the selected value from the dropdown list to the controller by @PathVariable

```
    @GetMapping(path ={"/test","/test/{serverName}
        public String loginfo(Model model, @PathVariable("serverName") Optional<String> serverName) {
    if(serverName.isPresent(){

    }
    else
    {

    }
return "testReportPage";
    }
```

html page :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/test/{serverName}(serverName=${server})}" method="get">
            <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Select Server</label>
            <div class="col-md-2 selectContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span> 
            <select name="server" id="server" th:field="*{serverlist}" 
            class="form-control selectpicker">
                    <option th:each="server : ${serverlist}" th:value="${server}"
                            th:text="${server}"></option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Filter</button>
            </div>
                        
</form>
```

I have multiple dropdown list in the html page, i need pass the selected value in the test/{}/{}

How can I do this?

Comment: If you really want to pass that as path variables, then you will need to use JavaScript to alter the `action` property of the form before the user uses the submit button. Any specific reason why you want to use path variables?

Comment: Not compulsory but i can use @RequestParam also, anyhow i need to pass the selected value. thats my goal,

Comment: In that case, just use `@ModelAttribute`. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: can you please check my updated controller, i want to use the same rest call based on optional value, can this work using @ModelAttribute?